# Random Decision Forest implementation with C#

Tags: random, decision-tree, random-forest, alglib

Hi I'm trying to use ALGLIB to calculate rdf. Unfortunately each of my training samples have more variables than two. I should use the function below but my training data has 7 variables. I think implementation of ALGLIB is implemented for just 2 variables. How can I achive to use it for 7 variabled training samples ?

```
public static void alglib.dfbuildrandomdecisionforestx1(
double[,] xy,
int npoints,
int nvars,
int nclasses,
int ntrees,
int nrndvars,
double r,
out int info,
out decisionforest df,
out dfreport rep)
```

Thanks in advance. I'm not insisting on using ALGLIB if there is another library which is proper for my training set and has implementation of random decision forest I can use it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should put all your training samples into two dimensional array of size [npoints, nvars+1] where npoints = number of training examples, nvars = number of variables(7 in your case) and the last column(+1) is for class label.

More information on parameteres you can find near the function definition.

For more information on dataset format read this -> [dataset format](http://www.alglib.net/dataanalysis/generalprinciples.php)

Comment: @esa55 did you ever figure out the correct format - do you have an example?